# Efficiently sorting linked list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, linked-list

What's the most efficient way to sort a linked list in Javascript/NodeJS? If I have an array of objects with an `id` and `comesAfter` which refers to the `id` of the previous item in the list, how can I put it in order?

ES6 features in the solution are fine to use. And it shouldn't modify the original array but return a new one. (But if it's not difficult to show how to do it in place that could help to see too.)

```
// before sorting
[
  { id: "three", comesAfter: "two" },
  { id: "one", comesAfter: null },
  { id: "four", comesAfter: "three" },
  { id: "two", comesAfter: "one" },
]

// after sorting
[
  { id: "one", comesAfter: null },
  { id: "two", comesAfter: "one" },
  { id: "three", comesAfter: "two" },
  { id: "four", comesAfter: "three" },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems reasonable to create an object, like this:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    obj[input[i].comesAfter] = input[i];
}
```

Now, let's generate the output:

```
var index = 0;
var output = [obj.null];
while (++index < input.length) {
    output[index] = obj[output[index - 1].id];
}
```